# How to remove rows from csv based on matching data

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, match

I have a large list of data in csv format which I need to remove rows from, based on matching two parameters.

My list of data to be removed would appear as follows:

```
London,James Smith
London,John Oliver
London,John-Smith-Harrison
Paris,Hermione
Paris,Trevor Wilson
New York City,Charlie Chaplin
New York City,Ned Stark
New York City,Thoma' Becket
New York City,Ryan-Dover
```

Then the main csv would remove a row based on matching the city name with the second column as well as matching the name with a name in the 9th column.

If both matched were achieved, delete the row in the main csv (note this csv hasn't been provided an example here).

Comment: Might be useful to state the question more obviously.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, what could I have done to make it more clear. Obviously it is in my interest to make the problem at hand as clear as possible. Kind regards AEA

Comment: I just wasn't sure if you were struggling with something, or just wanted for somebody to just write the code for you (which I've done below :P).

Comment: Have you managed to test it by now?

Comment: Yep thanks, works and accepted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I verified the following to work as you need on the kind of data you provided/described:

```
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO

# parse the data you're about to filter with
with open('filters.csv', 'rb') as f:
    filters = {(row[0], row[1]) for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')}

out_f = StringIO()  # use e.g. `with open('out.csv', 'wb') as out_f` for real file output
out = csv.writer(out_f, delimiter=',')

# go thru your rows and see if the pair (row[1], row[8]) is
# found in the previously parsed set of filters; if yes, skip the row
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
        if (row[1], row[8]) not in filters:
            out.writerow(row)

# for debugging only
print out_f.getvalue()  # prints the resulting filtered CSV data
```

**NOTE:** the `{... for ... in ...}` is set-comprehension syntax; depending on your Python version, you might need to change this to the equivalent `set(... for ... in ...)` for it to work.

Comment: Make sure to use `'rb'` and `'wb'` when opening files using the csv module.  To quote the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-contents): `it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.`  Use `newline=''` for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your data line by line and append line to list if its elements in 2nd and 9th columns are not in lists L1 and L2 respectively.

```
ext = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\\test.txt"
readL = []

f = open(ext)

for line in f:
    listLine = line.strip().split(',')
    if(listLine[2] in L1 or listLine[9] in L2):
        continue
    readL += [listLine]


f.close()
```

Comment: I believe he said if **both** row 2 as well as row 9 are found on the same line in the list of filters, skip the row; your code does something different; and it would be educational to also use idiomatic and nicely formatted Python in example snippets :) Also, the content of the `ext` variable is ill-formed because of backslashes; and your code doesn't show how to actually parse the contents of `L1` and `L2`; and `listLine[2]` is the 3rd row but he said 2nd; and it should be `readL.append(listLine)` etc... definitely looks like you're just after cheap rep.